# Exception has no "cause" parameter

Tags: java, exception

Many of the built in Java exceptions have no way to accept a `"cause"`. Is there any way to assign a cause to these exceptions?

I want to be able to chain exceptions, like with this `InterruptedException` example:

```
try{
    //threaded code
}catch (InterruptedException e){
    throw new InterruptedException("context-specific information", e);
}
```

If a constructor like this does not exist, what is the reasoning?

---

Edit: I've considered throwing either a different exception or runtime exception that accepts a cause parameter. The reason I haven't gone with either of these options is because I'm working within a framework that expects an `InterruptedException`, and not some other exception type.

Comment: What exceptions are you looking at that are missing a way to chain exceptions?

Comment: @Kayaman: At the moment, just InterruptedException.

Comment: @SteveSmith That's the `Exception` class. Constructors aren't inherited.

Comment: @Kayaman Here's an example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/UnsupportedAudioFileException.html

Comment: Why can't you just throw a different Exception that has a cause parameter?

Comment: Could you rethrow a RuntimeException (or similar) when receving the InterruptedException?

Comment: @SteveSmith Good question. I'm working within a framework that expects an InterruptedException (post updated).

Comment: Guys, I think he's asking *why* an exception would not accept a cause: "*If a constructor like this does not exist, what is the reasoning?*"

Comment: He also said *Is there any way to assign a cause to these exceptions?*

Comment: My guess as to why those exception don't have a constructor that accepts a cause: the cause isn't meant to be another exception, i.e. the exception itself is always the root cause (like the thread being interrupted).

Comment: One thing you could try would be to create a subclass of `InterruptedException` that accepts and stores a cause and override the `getCause()` method to return it. Alternatively you could try to call `initCause(...)` inside the constructor although you'd have to test this since the JavaDoc states this method is allowed to be called at most once.

Comment: You can use `initCause`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause(java.lang.Throwable)

Comment: From the JavaDoc as well as the sources it might be sufficient to do it that way: `throw new InterruptedException("context-specific information").initCause( e );`. As an example have a look at the sources for `Class.newInstance()` where you'll find this line: `new InstantiationException(getName()).initCause(e)`.

Comment: @ruakh Can you post your response as an answer so I can mark it as selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to assign a cause to these exceptions?

Yes; you can use [the `initCause(Throwable)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause-java.lang.Throwable-), which allows a cause to be set. It can only be called once for a given exception instance; it's specifically intended for this sort of case.

> If a constructor like this does not exist, what is the reasoning?

Oddly enough, even though the great majority of JDK exceptions do support taking causes, [the Javadoc for `java.lang.Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) seems to suggest that that's *not* the expected default. The Javadoc describes a few reasons that you might want to wrap an exception (neither of which applies in your case: they both have to do with wrapping an exception of one type in an exception of a different type), and it says that the cause-accepting constructors should only be created for "throwable classes that wish to allow causes to be associated with them" or even just for "subclasses that might *likely* have a cause associated with them" (emphasis mine).

I wonder if it's just that the JDK is behind the times; apparently causes were not originally intended to be used quite as generally as we now expect?

Answer (score 5):

The logical reason for an exception class missing a way to attach a cause, is that they can't have another exception as a cause.

Taking the exceptions given as examples, we've got `InterruptedException` and `UnsupportedAudioFileException`. Neither of those will have an exception as a cause, since `InterruptedException` cannot occur because of other exceptions, but only if a thread is interrupted.

`UnsupportedAudioFileException` on the other hand could take a cause, but it would be useless. There's no "deeper" reason for an audio file to not be supported.

Therefore it's no suprise that `NullPointerException` doesn't take a cause either. It's not like there are many reasons for that to happen...

If you're using an exception that doesn't take a wrapped exception in the constructor, you're probably using an exception that wasn't designed for that sort of use. While the ready made "general exceptions" like `IllegalArgumentException` do take (and even expect) causes to be included, if you can't find an existing one that fits your use case, create your own exception.

If you're working with a framework that expects an `InterruptedException`, there are 2 possibilities. Either it was chosen because of the name ("Hey, stopping this job should throw InterruptedException") or it was chosen because of sane design choices. You should first make sure you're not using the framework wrong, since `InterruptedException` is not a general use case exception and implies interrupted threads.

Comment: I was writing a very similar answer. Then I challenged myself to find an exception that is too abstract to exist alone, yet has no `cause` parameter. [DestroyFailedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/DestroyFailedException.html). Not saying your answer is wrong, +1, but I would love to hear what people have to say about this exception.

Comment: I personally believe that every exception should have the opportunity to specify a cause for cases like mine, where the context is important but so is the underlying root cause. This becomes even more important as the call depth of the application grows.

Comment: @Gladclef Do you mean that even though an `InterruptedException` or `NullPointerException` can never have a cause (unless you're misusing it in your own code), you still think it should be possible to specify a cause? If so, care to explain why?

Comment: If the context (aka message) is as important as the cause, then there should be a way to add context at various levels of the call depth. The only way I know of to do this is to throw a new instance of the exception with the original exception as the cause.
So, maybe the proper solution is to have InterruptedException accept a cause of type InterruptedException?

Comment: @Gladclef No, the proper solution is not to use a specific existing exception for your own purposes. Don't throw `NullPointerExceptions`, `InterruptedExceptions` etc., instead switch to another exception or create your own.

Comment: @Kayaman What might be a specific example for this case? (example do as Thomas suggested and extend InterruptedException with my own class that accepts both a message and a cause)

Comment: @Gladclef Well in this case I'd examine why the framework is expecting an `InterruptedException` and, does it **really** expect it's created and thrown by you instead of the normal way. I suspect there's a deeper *puzzle* here that the question doesn't reveal.